# How to change ckEditors config.colorButton_colors

Tags: configuration, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I previously did this by hacking

```
config.colorButton_colors = 'fff,eee,ccc,aaa,999,666,333,000';
```

into

```
./sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/ckeditor/config.js
```

the config has moved .. I can probably still do this in the bower_components, but it makes it all too clear it's a hack and will again be overridden in due time.

So, is there a place to customize ckeditor config safely, and more advanded than the wizard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. The question is sufficiently answered here

[How do I override the default CKEditor configuration?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4523/how-do-i-override-the-default-ckeditor-configuration?rq=1)

The file I was looking for is

```
sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/crm-ckeditor-config.js
```

but it isn't 100% permanent :-/