# Has anyone had success in embedding videos into CKEditor in CiviCRM

Tags: ckeditor

Following on from my question [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/29189/ckeditor-in-civicrm-is-it-possible-to-have-a-custom-css-file), we are wondering if anyone has successfully embedded videos into CKEditor in Civi. We want to put videos into our event descriptions.

We can embed a vimeo or YouTube video into CKEditor easily enough, by copying the embed code into Source.

We can then make the public view look great - floating the video and making it responsive etc etc.

However, inside the wysiwyg view it is very limited. It's just a 300x150px preview of the video that we can't seem to get any control over. We can't click it... and therefore can't apply styles from our custom styles.js file to it.

Also, it's fixed - we can't drag it about - and it's inline (ie no text wrap) and merely a small thumbnail. So not at all wysiwyg - and our admin teams are used to sites that are beautifully easy to use these days... and so get a bit exasperated when they have to use trial and error to see how the video will look after they've saved the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: So sorry - Civicrm 5.10 and Drupal 7.66. It's perhaps worth noting that we have a nice solution in Drupal that's both responsive and styleable in CKEditor with the Wysiwyg module, using Widgets and the Wysiwyg Media Embed module. However, we haven't been able to find a way to get close to this in CKEditor in Civi.

Comment: Have you tried the FitVids module? Fits videos to 100% width of the container.