# How do I set the default font type and font size in ckeditor configuration?

Tags: ckeditor, default-settings

I'm trying to configure a site so email messages (Contact>send an email) default to Arial- 12 point.

I can see the CK Editor config options in Display preferences, but am struggling to decipher the linked API documentation.

Anyone give me a clue?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not quite what you are looking for, but I forced font size in a letter by adding a  tag in a message template. I had it put it into {literal} {/literal} (to escape the smarty processing if I remember correctly).

If you wanted that to apply more generally, maybe you could put it in a header.

Comment: Thanks Mick, it might not be quite what I need, but it may give me something to look at/ think about.

Sorry for the delay in acknowledging got stuck on other issues but now circling back round to this one.

Comment: @CraigAlmond - did you find a solution for this?  https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/22260/225 is related, but different.