# Add a new font to CKEditor 4 on WP

Tags: ckeditor

I need to use a specific governmental font to create PDF.

I've read and followed [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22260/additional-fonts-ckeditor/22957#22957) without any success until now. Maybe my configuration has to be different due to WP / CiviCRM 5.60 and our CentOS server.

This is what I've done:

- checked that the `Font` plugin is active in CKEditor

[image]

- created a `customfonts` folder in `/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/`
- created a `font.css` file in the `/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/customfonts` folder
- uploaded there a font called `Marianne.otf`

[image]

- added a line in the `fonts.css` file

> config.font_names = "Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive;Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace;Georgia/Georgia, serif;Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;Marianne/Marianne, sans-serif;Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif";

- added extra instruction for Nginx (on CentOS 7) that includes `otf` font type

> location ~
> ^/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/customfonts/.+.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$
> {     add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"; }

- added an option in CKEditor's Advander Options to declare the path for the `fonts.css` file which should be `/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/customfonts/fonts.css`

[image]

- verified the new `config.contentsCss = '/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/customfonts/fonts.css';` option in the `crm-ckeditor-default.js` file
- flushed all caches including Browser's ones
- read again the documentation
- checked the permissions for the `crm-ckeditor-default.js` file
- controlled that no Marianne font is added when working on a message template

[image]

What I noticed here:

- creating a ../civicrm/persist/crm-ckeditor-custom.js file doesn't change anything. I actually don't even see it in the editor

[image]

- the editor in message template doesn't use the right theme

like here

[image]

when it should be like there

[image]

- I've added the `print` plugin in the toolbar

[image]

and actually it doesn't either show up

[image]

instead of

[image]

So there might be something stuck not on CKEditor's side but maybe more on the message template's one but I can't be sure because I've also added the `justify` plugin and it shows up in the Editor in message template

[image]

Any hints?