# Civimail strips html when switching from source to wysiwyg editor

Tags: civimail, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I use a separate email editor to code emails before copying and pasting into civicrm to send.

I have noticed that if I copy and paste into source and press send without looking at it in the wysiwyg editor the code works as expected.

If I look at it first the following code is stripped out. I am not a proficient email coder - this is what the programme I use puts in.

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><head>`

The editor is CKeditor. Can I stop it doing this? I have a work around but if I could stop it (or understand if there's a good reason why it is doing it) that would be better!

Thanks
Caroline

New information: I think part of the answer is here. [How do I override the default CKEditor configuration?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4523/how-do-i-override-the-default-ckeditor-configuration)
If that's right I'm not still not sure what I need to do! If anyone can help that woudl be great :)

Comment: You say "the following code is stripped out" - but i don't see the code pasted. Can you add some examples, and perhaps explain what programme you are copying this from.

Comment: Hello - sorry I realised after your comment that I hadn't formatted my post correctly. I have also managed to get this to work (I think) by goign to admin console, display preferences, configure wysiwyg editor, email,  and adding fullpage = true. I'm reluctant to post this is as a correct answer - but it seems to work for me! Thank you for replying!

Comment: I think any answer that works deserves posting as an Answer ;-)